# What's the real meaning about 'Everything that exists is an object' in R?

Tags: r

I saw:

> “To understand computations in R, two slogans are helpful:
>
> •   Everything that exists is an object.
>     •   Everything that happens is a function call."
>
> — John Chambers

But I just found:

```
a <- 2
is.object(a)
# FALSE
```

Actually, if a variable is a pure base type, it's result is.object() would be FALSE. So it should not be an object.

So what's the real meaning about 'Everything that exists is an object' in R?

Comment: For many programming languages, I suppose you can only call 'x'  is a variable, not an object, if 'x' only have a value.

Comment: This quote is less about the what answer `is.object()` gives but about the internal representation of everything in R -- see Dirk Eddelbuettel's answer.  It especially means that e.g. functions are objects too, and formulas, and expressions are objects, and ... (... given the quote, `is.object()` would be quite useless since EVERYTHING is an object)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The function `is.object` seems only to look if the object has a "class" attribute. So it has not the same meaning as in the slogan.

For instance:

```
x <- 1
attributes(x) # it does not have a class attribute
NULL
is.object(x)
[1] FALSE
class(x) <- "my_class"
attributes(x) # now it has a class attribute
$class
[1] "my_class"
is.object(x)
[1] TRUE
```

Now, trying to answer your real question, about the slogan, this is how I would put it. Everything that exists in `R` is an object in the sense that it is a kind of data structure that can be manipulated. I think this is better understood with functions and expressions, which are not usually thought as data.

Taking a quote from Chambers (2008):

> The central computation in R is a function call, defined by the
>   function object itself and the objects that are supplied as the
>   arguments. In the functional programming model, the result is defined
>   by another object, the value of the call. Hence the traditional motto
>   of the S language: everything is an object—the arguments, the value,
>   and in fact the function and the call itself: All of these are defined
>   as objects. Think of objects as collections of data of all kinds. The data contained and the way the data is organized depend on the class from which the object was generated.

Take this expression for example `mean(rnorm(100), trim = 0.9)`. Until it is is evaluated, it is an object very much like any other. So you can change its elements just like you would do it with a list. For instance:

```
call <- substitute(mean(rnorm(100), trim = 0.9))
call[[2]] <- substitute(rt(100,2 ))
call
mean(rt(100, 2), trim = 0.9)
```

Or take a function, like `rnorm`:

```
rnorm
function (n, mean = 0, sd = 1) 
.Call(C_rnorm, n, mean, sd)
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

You can change its default arguments just like a simple object, like a list, too:

```
formals(rnorm)[2] <- 100
rnorm
function (n, mean = 100, sd = 1) 
.Call(C_rnorm, n, mean, sd)
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Taking one more time from Chambers (2008):

> The key concept is that expressions for evaluation are themselves
>   objects; in the traditional motto of the S language, everything is an
>   object. Evaluation consists of taking the object representing an
>   expression and returning the object that is the value of that
>   expression.

So going back to our call example, the `call` is an object which represents another object. When evaluated, it becomes that other object, which in this case is the numeric vector with one number: -0.008138572.

```
set.seed(1)
eval(call)
[1] -0.008138572
```

And that would take us to the second slogan, which you did not mention, but usually comes together with the first one: "Everything that happens is a function call".

Taking again from Chambers (2008), he actually qualifies this statement a little bit:

> Nearly everything that happens in R results from a function call.
>   Therefore, basic programming centers on creating and refining
>   functions.

So what that means is that almost every transformation of data that happens in `R` is a function call. Even a simple thing, like a parenthesis, is a function in `R`.

So taking the parenthesis like an example, you can actually redefine it to do things like this:

```
`(` <- function(x) x + 1
(1)
[1] 2
```

Which is not a good idea but illustrates the point. So I guess this is how I would sum it up: Everything that exists in R is an object because they are data which can be manipulated. And (almost) everything that happens is a function call, which is an evaluation of this object which gives you another object.

Comment: Hi @Carlos, I suppose now I know the definition of "object" in R. As you said, a object just is a kind of data structure that can be manipulated. That's quite different with other Languages, such as Python, Ruby, Java. I suppose that's because R has different class system.

Comment: and is.object(x) is FALSE, only mean this object has not attributes yet. That's it. And actually, I don't think R has real class system, and R don't need it. Since it's a functional language, all class systems are just syntactic sugar, and a little ugly.

Answer (score 11):

I love that quote.

In another (as of now unpublished) write-up, the author continues with

> R has a uniform internal structure for representing all objects. The evaluation process keys off that structure, in a simple form that is essentially
>   composed of function calls, with objects as arguments and an object as the
>   value. Understanding the central role of objects and functions in R makes
>   use of the software more effective for any challenging application, even those where extending R is not the goal.

but then spends several hundred pages expanding on it.  It will be a great read once finished.

Answer (score 11):

**Objects** For `x` to be an object means that it has a class thus `class(x)` returns a class for every object.  Even functions have a class as do environments and other objects one might not expect:

```
class(sin)
## [1] "function"

class(.GlobalEnv)
## [1] "environment"
```

I would not pay too much attention to `is.object`.  `is.object(x)` has a slightly different meaning than what we are using here -- it returns TRUE if `x` has a class name internally stored along with its value.  If the class is stored then `class(x)` returns the stored value and if not then `class(x)` will compute it from the type.  From a conceptual perspective it matters not how the class is stored internally (stored or computed) -- what matters is that in both cases `x` is still an object and still has a class.

**Functions** That all computation occurs through functions refers to the fact that even things that you might not expect to be functions are actually functions.  For example when we write:

```
{ 1; 2 }
## [1] 2

if (pi > 0) 2 else 3
## [1] 2

1+2
## [1] 3
```

we are actually making invocations of the `{`, `if` and `+` functions:

```
`{`(1, 2)
## [1] 2

`if`(pi > 0, 2, 3)
## [1] 2

`+`(1, 2)
## [1] 3
```