# How to correctly `save` a function which uses variables from the global namespace?

Tags: r, rdata

- I have two instruments A, B which are 'off' from each other with some systematic error. E.g. A consistently reads +5 away from B.
- So, I need a function `A_to_B` which maps readings of A to B, e.g. A = B + 5
- I wrote this function in a script, using a linear model of A against B.
- But, I use these instruments everywhere else, so I'll need this in other scripts.
- So, I try to `save` the function.

```
AB.readings <- read.csv('AB.csv')
AvB.lm <- lm(A~B+I(B^2), data=AB.readings)
A_to_B <- function(a) {
    coeff <- AvB.lm$coefficients - c(a, 0, 0)
    roots <- Re(polyroot(coeff))
    return(roots[roots>=0])  # A, B readings > 0
}
save(AvB.lm, A_to_B, file='calibration.RData')
```

But, when I try to load and use this function in other scripts:

```
source('calibration.RData')
AB.readings <- read.csv('AB2.csv')
AB.readings$A <- A_to_B(AB.readings$A)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in A_to_B(AB.readings$A) : object 'AvB.lm' not found
Execution halted
```

So obviously I've done something wrong with the scoping.

---

What's the right way to do this in R?

Comment: Suppose I don't want to re-run `lm` each time (plus, I would have to load the 'training' CSV data each time, which seems tricky when I am in different working directories). Is there no other way?

Comment: @RAB why is Rdata for data, not a function? Rdata file can save any R objects, including functions.

Comment: @RAB in R, functions are first-class objects

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `load` and not `source`. From the docs:

> `save` writes an external representation of R objects to the specified file. The objects can be read back from the file at a later date by using the function `load` or `attach` (or `data` in some cases).

Side note: RAB's comment above (*Rdata is for data, not a function.*) is not correct, and `save` will save functions, too. Recall that [everything in R is an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376318/whats-the-real-meaning-about-everything-that-exists-is-an-object-in-r), including functions. `save` writes external representations of R objects, so it follows that `save` will also write external representations of functions.

Comment: My mistake, that was a typo copying my script over as MWE. I did use load instead of source, but the scoping did not 'translate' right, since the lm object I'm referring to isn't bound to that functional scope per se.

Comment: @ning it doesn't have to be bound to the function's local scope. If a function can't find an object locally it looks in the next environment up. Using `source` I am able to replicate your issue. When I replace it with `load` I no longer get the error message. I would suggest that you edit your question with a reproducible example if that doesn't fix it for you.

Comment: I see, thanks! I'm away from my computer right now, but I'll try it out and update you when I have the time.