# Relation between primitive data types and classes in R

Tags: java, r, class, types

Regarding the relation between primitive data types (like numeric or character) and classes in R:
Is it reasonable to say that primitive data types are built-in classes in R, for which the operations (like + or -) correspond to the built-in methods?
Are the primitive data types also implemented internally as classes (unlike Java which distinguishes between primitive data types and wrapper classes)?

Comment: Types and classes are different concepts. Types primarily correspond to what data type is used in the underlying C code. In contrast, classes are an R concept. Note that R has several different OOP systems, the main one being S3 classes. The confusing part might be that there are implicit classes corresponding to the data types (everything in R has an explicit or implicit S3 class).

Comment: @Roland I think you sould post this as an answer.

Comment: You cannot create new types in R. You can only create new classes, which must be based on existing types.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376318/whats-the-real-meaning-about-everything-that-exists-is-an-object-in-r

Answer (score 2):

Types and classes are different concepts. Types primarily correspond to what data type is used in the underlying C code. Quoting Chapter 2 of the [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Object_002doriented-programming):

> The R specific function typeof returns the type of an R object. Note
>   that in the C code underlying R, all objects are pointers to a
>   structure with typedef SEXPREC; the different R data types are
>   represented in C by SEXPTYPE, which determines how the information in
>   the various parts of the structure is used.

In contrast, classes are an R concept. Note that R has several different OOP systems, the main one being S3 classes. The confusing part might be that there are implicit classes corresponding to the data types (everything in R has an explicit or implicit S3 class).

Let's use data.frames as an example:

```
#create an object of type "list"
x <- list(a = 1, b = 2)

typeof(x)
#[1] "list"

class(x)
#[1] "list"
#this is an implicit class

attributes(x)
#$names
#[1] "a" "b"
#no class attribute

class(x) <- "data.frame" 
attr(x,"row.names") <- 1L
#don't create data.frames this way, I only do this for didactic reasons

x
#  a b
#1 1 2

attributes(x)
#$names
#[1] "a" "b"
#
#$class
#[1] "data.frame"
#
#$row.names
#[1] 1

is.data.frame(x)
#[1] TRUE

class(x)
#[1] "data.frame"
#this is an explicit class

typeof(x)
#[1] "list"
#still the same type
```

Comment: @ Roland thanks a lot for your answer. I am thinking now about two things: I am right that when I am customizing a new data type by writing a class, I am actually not really creating a new type? Continuing with this logic, non-primitive types like data frames are then also not really types in this sense?

Comment: You are using the word "type" when you mean "class". The type of an object of class "data.frame" is "list". You can find a complete list of all types in R in `help("typeof")`.

Comment: Added an example that should clarify this.

Comment: @ Roland thanks a lot.
What is a bit confusing for me is that in Java, I often read that someone created a new "data typ" when a new class was written. Is this just a careless and imprecise way of using the word "data type"?
In practice, how does it materialize when I am using primitive data types compared to objects from classes, i.e. what is the difference between handeling a realization of a primitive data type and an instance from a class in R?

Comment: I don't know Java. As I said: everything in R has a class, you are always handling classes and don't need to care too much about types unless you are doing advanced stuff.