# Extracting estimates from double nested list

Tags: r, nested-lists

I am trying to extract the `CIs` (confidence intervals) from a double-nested list that looks as follows:
[image]

I am able to do so with the following very ugly code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
cis <- as.data.frame(L1.estimates[["CIs"]])
cil <- cis[1,]
cil <- melt(cil)
cil <- cil %>% dplyr::select(-c(1)) %>% dplyr::rename(conf.low = 1)
cih <- cis[2,]
cih <- melt(cih)
cih <- cih %>% dplyr::select(-c(1)) %>% dplyr::rename(conf.high = 1)
CIs <- cbind(cil,cih)
```

However, it produces the following warning: "No id variables; using all as measure variables". What is the cleaner way to do what I did? There is clearly a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce can be used to collapse lists.

```
l <- list(
  L1 = list(
    Xs = 1:5,
    coefs = 1:5,
    CI = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6)
    )
)

Reduce(rbind.data.frame, l$L1$CI) |> setNames(c("low", "high"))
#>   low high
#> 1   1    2
#> 2   3    4
#> 3   5    6
```

Or, using `purrr`, one can alternatively do

```
transpose(l$L1$CI, c("low", "high")) %>% map_dfr(unlist)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Donald! Would Reduce() work within a function? If so, how would it work with assigning your answer to a data frame?

Comment: @Mike [everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376318/whats-the-real-meaning-about-everything-that-exists-is-an-object-in-r) that happens in R is a function call. Thus, anything can be extended to take place in a function. Here it could `f <- function(x) Reduce(rbind.data.frame, x) |> setNames(c("low", "high"))`, where it is called via `df <- f(l$L1$CI)`, assigning the result to a new data.frame

Answer (score 1):

A `purrr` approach:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
l %>% 
  map( ~.x[contains("CI", vars = names(.x))]) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  tidyr::separate(col = "CI", into = c("low", "high"), sep = ":")
```